# add data on 2 table at the same time zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i have two table

### Table sale :

```
 id_sale    int
 id_projet  int
 price      float
 date       date
```

### Table sale_ligne:

```
id_sale_ligne  int
id_sale        int FK_SALE
id_projet      int
price          float
date           date
```

i m asking how can i insert a record on sale_line with same id_sale when i make a new record on sale .
I know it's a large question but i m really stuck here and i can find this exemple on official ZF documentation , so any one can help me with suggestion or a reference with full exemple that explain my case

Great Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of accomplishing this. The easiest one is probably to just execute another SQL query after your first insertion into `sale`. You could do something like this:

```
// Insert sale and get the ID
$this->dbAdapter->query('INSERT INTO sale (price, date) VALUES (?, ?)', array('price', 'date'));
$salesId = $this->dbAdapter->getDriver()->getLastGeneratedValue();

$this->dbAdapter->query('INSERT INTO sale_ligne (price, date, id_sale) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', array('price', 'date', $salesId));
```

Please not that error handling has been omitted in the above example. The `getLastGeneratedValue` method will return the last generated ID, assuming that you are using auto incrementing on your primary key in the `sale` table.

Alternatively you could do the same thing in a stored procedure by using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. Due to the nature of your tables, you will probably want to specify the data that is to be inserted into the `sale_ligne` table (i.e. the values do not equal the default column values). Otherwise it would perhaps be possible to add an insert trigger on the `sale` table and do the insertion within that trigger. The first approach or within a stored procedure would, however, be easier to implement and give you more control as well as make the flow of your process easier to understand for other developers.

Comment: Great thanks for you'r responce , i was testing the  $salesId = $this->dbAdapter->getDriver()->getLastGeneratedValue(); and all work fine i get the last Id with (Var_Dump test) just asking where  exactly i put the sql request ( controller or SaleTable )  i m new with ZF2 and i really apreciate you'r help

Comment: You are welcome. I am happy to help. You should not put database logic within the controller, so in your case it should be within the `SaleTable` class. A controller should be responsible for controlling the _flow_ of a request. You can think of it as a coordinator. Therefore, the actual database communication should be done in a separate layer (the `SaleTable` in this case), where the controller invokes methods in this class. E.g. in the controller: `$result = $this->getSaleTable()->insert('price', 'date');`.

Comment: You are very welcome. Glad it worked for you. Please accept the answer so that the question will appear as solved on the list. :-)